# The difference between python dict and tr1::unordered_map in C++

Tags: c++, python, dictionary, hashmap, tr1

I have a question related to understanding of how python dictionaries work.

I remember reading somewhere strings in python are immutable to allow hashing, and it is the same reason why one cannot directly use lists as keys, i.e. the lists are mutable (by supporting .append) and hence they cannot be used as dictionary keys.

I wanted to know how does implementation of unordered_map in C++ handles these cases. (since strings in C++ are mutable)

Comment: Wish I could edit posts, so I could edit away the "'" in "dict's"... ;-)  (Yes, I'm in a snarky mood ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Keys in all C++ map/set containers are const and thus immutable (after added to the container).

Notice that C++ containers are not specific to string keys, you can use any objects, but the constness will prevent modifications after the key is copied to the container.

Comment: What will happen if someone uses const_cast to mess around with keys.
Thanks

Comment: Reference: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Map.html -- `value_type` is defined as "The type of object, `pair<const key_type, data_type>`, stored in the map."  Note the `const`.

Comment: @Akshay: if someone does that, they get what they deserve :)  `std::map` is implemented using a red-black tree.  Changing a key would invalidate the tree.  `unordered_map` is implemented using a hash table.  Changing a key would mean you likely would never find that item again, because it would probably be in the wrong hash bucket for its new key.

Comment: @Akshay @Dan: More specifically, modifying a const object through a `const_cast` leads to undefined behavior.